# Large white space gap between elements on mobile (though not appearing via inspect element mobile view)

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am having a mysterious issue where there is a large white space gap between a fieldset and button element via html.  As you can see below, when I inspect element and go into mobile view on firefox (on my laptop) everything seems to be formatted fine.  But when I actually load my page via a mobile device that white space gap appears.  How could this be the case.

Wouldnt the same white gap appear in the mobile view inspect element on firefox laptop?  This makes me think its not quite a @media sizing issue in CSS but something else?  Any help is truly appreciated.

[image: Inspect element view via macbook pro laptop screen]

[image: Mobile iPhone7/8 screenshot view]

Comment: a) What mobile platform and browser you're having the issue with and b) are you using any floats maybe? A snippet of the css and HTML markup would be helpful!

Comment: i'm actually using a bootstrap template for css (so the code has thousands of lines).  Any idea the best way to post that here ?

Comment: @exside a)  ive tested it on firefox/safari/duckduckgo mobile browser all with the same white space gap

Comment: on iOS? If yes, that doesn't really matter, because all browser on iOS use Safari under the hood =)...no matter if it says "firefox"...apple doesn't allow it. Did you test on Safari desktop?

Comment: @exside yes actually, but its the same issue with safari as well :(

Comment: @i can get them closer together by adjusting margin-bottom and it seems to look better view mobile now but when i decrease the size on laptop it all overlaps.  It's as though mobile vs browser via are not synced to the same html/css code...

Comment: @exside ok update, based on what you said about under the hood all brosers use Safari on iOS, I used Safari to inspect element on my page and now im seeing its clearly an iOS issue with the way its displaying.  Any idea how I can adjust this for only iOS ?  im at a loss right now

Comment: ended up using inspect element and found it was a django form that for whatever reason had occupied height 100%, removed it and its fine now.  Thanks for the insight @exside